# Linter error in Deno project tsconfig.json, and cascading into project files - but code runs successfully?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, deno

I need to use the ES2019 `flatMap()` method on an array in a Deno project, so I have created a tsconfig.json file as below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es2019"
        ]
    }
}
```

This gives what appear to be 6 of the same linter errors, specifically `Cannot find type definition file for 'cacheable-request'` in the tsconfig.json file. Have I created this file incorrectly or somehow caused conflict with the Deno structure?

In a project module where I am attempting to use `flatMap()` I am seeing the error

```
Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'number[][]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later.
```

This doesn't make much sense since I have set my `lib` to `es2019` in my tsonfig - unless I've created it wrong and it's thus not being picked up... then again the code works, so I'm assuming that it has correctly compiled to `es2019`.

Am I missing some aspect of creating a tsconfig file for a Deno project that allows use of `es2019`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no need normally to include a `tsconfig.json` in order to use ES2019 features in Deno. I was able to use `flatMap` without problems in Deno `1.9.0`, for example:

```js
// mod.ts
const map = [1,2,3,[1,2,3],[1,2]].flatMap((_value, _index, _array) => {
    return 1;
});

console.log(map);
```

```
deno run mod.ts 
>> [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
```

I couldn't find if this was unsupported or bugged in previous versions but try upgrading Deno and omitting `tsconfig.json` to fix this.